# Is it possible to change the query string value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

Let me know Is their any possibility to change the query string value? i have tried 
like the following:

```
  Dim tab As Integer = CInt(Request.QueryString("tab"))
  Request.QueryString("tab") = ""
```

but it says `System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.`. does it means that assigning values to the query string only at the time of redirection using `Response.Redirect(----)`?

I know i can use session or cookies instead for this.

Comment: You can't change QueryString.

Comment: Depending on your issue, it is a good idea to store the query string in a variable and use that variable throughout your application. That way you can manipulate that value during a post back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it means that assigning values to the query string only at the time of redirection

Yes. The query string comes from the request the browser makes. You can't change a request that is being processed. You'll have to redirect using the new query string values.

Comment: ok thank you for the response. i can't up vote due to lack of points

Answer (score 1):

[HttpRequest.QueryString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for *Gets the collection of HTTP query string variables.* QueryString  dos not support set value operation

Comment: ok thank you for the response. i can't up vote due to lack of points